# Why does "apt-get update" need sudo, but using "Software updater" doesn't?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I think it's really strange that `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` need sudo. But why doesn't using `Software Updater` need it as welll?

I mean, I can install (almost) all updates without even being sudo, making Software Updater an easier (and maybe more safe) way to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you silently authenticate via PolicyKit when running the Software Updater. Part of the 'secret' is in the file

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

more exactly via this entry:

```
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Well, saying that, it means that If I leave the Software Updater open (maybe you forgot to close while surfing the web), it means that the user is in sudo mode? Or the sudo is only avaible for the Software Updater (the rest of the computer is in the "normal" mode)

Comment: @Nori-chan: The latter is true. Via PolicyKit you can pick certain procedures with certain applications where you don't need to authenticate via password. For instance, when Software Updater prompts you to install a new kernel version, it asks for password, since it involves new packages, which is not covered by the PolicyKit rule.

Comment: Let's see if I got the idea: with PolicyKit, I can choose what commands I want to have with sudo access, and what commands don't need it. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nori-chan: If you really want to understand, you'd better go to e.g. [this page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html).